# Drop duplicates function usage followed by self join count in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have the below code implemented in Spark:

```
val testDFDedup = testDF.dropDuplicates(Seq("A", "B"))
val count1 = testDF.join(testDFDedup, Seq("A", "B")).count()
val count2 = testDF.count()
```

Now, my understanding is that `count1` should be equal to `count2`, since line two takes an inner join and the join expression implemented above should match all the rows. Yet I am facing the issue where the counts are off, and I am trying to understand why that might be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testDF.show
+----+---+---+
|   A|  B|  C|
+----+---+---+
|   1|  2|  3|
|   1|  2|  4|
|null|  3|  4|
|null|  3|  5|
+----+---+---+
```

For this dataframe, you'll get `count = 2` and `countDF = 4`. You can't join on null keys, so you got a smaller than expected count.